# Screen Shot of image clicked react-naitve

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have multiple graphs on my screen, however I want to share the image of graph on which i have clicked. I am using https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share to share the content and https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot to capture the entire screen. Is there is any way to capture the image on which i have clicked and get the uri.?

Answer (score 0):

I think one possible solution is when the user clicked on the graph, you can navigate him to a new screen and send and send graph data as param to it. In the new screen display that specific graph using param data and take screenshot then.
and finally share it.